# Selecting multiple img using alt on click in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a project that makes it so when I click on a thumbnail the picture is supposed to enlarge and display the name (alt) of the picture below it.. I have gotten it to almost work, but no matter what thumbnail I click, it only displays one of the images..
**html**

```
<div id="vacationimages">
    <p>  Click on the Image that best represents the kind of vacation you want</p>
    <p>  <img src="mountain link" alt="Mountain Vacation"></p>
    <p>  <img src="desert link" alt="Desert Vacation"></p>
    <p>  <img src="ocean link" alt="Ocean Vacation"></p>
</div>

<div id="bigimage">
    <img id="currentimage" src="ocean link" alt="ocean vacation" width="300" height="225" border="0"
    <p id="imagedesc">  </p>
</div>
```

---

**Javascript/jQuery**

```
$('#vacationimages').each(function() 
{
    var vacaimg = new Image();
    vacaimg.src = $(this).attr("src");
});

$('#vacationimages').click(function(event) {
    var imgsrc = $(this).attr('src');
    var imgalt = $(this).attr('alt');
    $("#bigimage").toggle('');
    $(this).css('display', '');

    event.stopPropagation();

    var imagedisc = $(this).attr(imgalt);
    $('#imagedisc').text(imagedisc);
});
```

I hope this is legible. I was unable to give actual picture links, but hopefully this gives you a good idea.

*I also cannot change the HTML so only javascript changes please.*

*edit#1* here is the JSFiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/CodeGirl91/kfnzngu8/

also, not everything on the project is useable, aka the hide and submit button, I am only worried about the pictures at the moment. *end of edit#1*

Comment: The HTML does not look valid; that would have to be the first thing to change. Can you fix that so we can begin to help you? And can you clear indicate exactly what it is you need help with?

Comment: If you are able to provide a JSFiddle demonstrating the issue, this will get solved a lot quicker.

Comment: I agreed with @KyleMuir's comment.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CodeGirl91/kfnzngu8/ here is the JSFiddle, I didn't put the entire code into the section because it was so long, but that is the full project.

Comment: you always want display "`bigimage`" whether you click on image 1 , 2 or 3? is that what you want? if I understand correctly...

Comment: @dippas yes. when you click on any of the images, it needs to display within "bigimage"

Comment: Sorry if I'm not very clear right away.. I'm not used to asking for help..

Comment: @dippas, your code has the same problem.  When any image is selected, it only shows one of the images.

Comment: @CodeGirl91, Welcome to StackOverflow! Asking questions here is just like anything else, the more you do it, the better you will get! If an answer helps you out, please click the tick to indicate that it is your accpeted answer. If you have any questions regarding my (or any) answer, feel free to ask in the comments section of the answer.

Comment: $('#vacationimages').on('click','img',function(...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your problems is that you are capturing the click on the div surrounding you thumb nails. Also you are assigning a few thing inccorectly

```js
$('#vacationimages img').click(function(event) {
    var imgsrc = $(this).attr('src');
    var imgalt = $(this).attr('alt');
  
  console.log(imgsrc);
  
    /*Not exacly sure what you are tring to do here*/
    /*So commented out for now*/
    /*$("#bigimage").toggle('');
    $(this).css('display', '');*/
    /*Taking a guess at what you want*/
    $("#bigimage").show();

    $("#currentimage").attr("src", imgsrc);
    event.stopPropagation();
  
    var imagedisc = $(this).attr(imgalt);
    $('#imagedesc').html(imgalt);
  
});
```

```css
#vacationimages img
{
  height:75px;
}

#bigimage
{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="vacationimages">
    <p>  Click on the Image that best represents the kind of vacation you want</p>
    <p>  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/ff0000/ffffff&text=MountainVacation" alt="Mountain Vacation"></p>
    <p>  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/00ff00/ffffff&text=DesertVacation" alt="Desert Vacation"></p>
    <p>  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/0000ff/ffffff&text=OceanVacation" alt="Ocean Vacation"></p>
</div>

<div id="bigimage">
    <img id="currentimage" src="ocean link" alt="ocean vacation" />
    <p id="imagedesc">  </p>
</div>
```

Note that I've taken out the `height` and `width` attributes from `bigimage`. The main reason I did that is that the aspect ratio was diferent from the quick and dirty images I chose. They can stay there, but note that they are depricated in HTML and have been for some time.

Comment: the only thing you add it here was `img` to be clicked, if you removed it does the same work. Unless I'm not seeing nor understanding fully OPs question. http://jsfiddle.net/2beuvh0y/

Comment: @dippas The OP wants to update the "Big Image" with the image clicked. Your link does not do that. There were other less apparent errors than the obvious one of not capturing the image clicked.

Comment: Your doesn't do that as well. I didn't see any changes :O am I seeing wrong? btw using FF..

Comment: Yes, it does. The original didn't as there were the other issues that I mentioned.

Comment: Grey on grey images were a bit subtle! I've made it more obvious.